# Cannot use command line Elixir mix (macOS High Sierra)

Tags: erlang, elixir

When i run command `elixir -v` or `mix`, it will return:

```
{"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{elixir,start_cli,[],[]},{init,start_em,1,[]},{init,do_boot,3,[]}]}}

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

Some details:

> `$ brew list`
>   `elixir    erlang` ...
>
> `$ erl`
>   `Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.0] [source-6dc93c1] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]`
>   `Eshell V8.0  (abort with ^G)
>   1>`
>
> `$ elixir`
>   `Usage: elixir [options] [.exs file] [data]`
>   
>     `-e COMMAND                  Evaluates the given command (*)
>     -r FILE                     Requires the given files/patterns (*)`
>   
>   ...

I have used brew uninstall, reinstall, but nothing change. Please help me fix it!

Comment: In the past when I've seen that "init terminating in do_boot" it has always come down to an issue with something being installed incorrectly.  Try cleaning everything out and reinstalling all of it.

Answer (score 0):

`erl` without any arguments will run Erlang shell. But if you want to [run Elixir shell](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/introduction.html#interactive-mode) you should try running `iex` (interactive elixir).  `elixir` is used to [run programs](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/introduction.html#running-scripts) you already coded, like `elixir simple.exs`

Or it might be that your Erlang version is little out of date. Try running `brew update`.

Comment: Thank you, but i already did it. I have tried to reinstall Erlang with version 18.0, 19.0 and now 20. <br /> When I type '$ elixir' + <something>, '$ mix' + <something>, it alsways return " {"init terminating in do_boot",{undef .... init terminating in do_boot () "

Comment: It looks like Erlang VM can not find `elixir.beam` files. Could you check if you really have it installed? Try to find `elixir` with `where`